# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top') happens on every page except homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I currently get a jQuery error that is driving me crazy.

"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')"

I implemented a simple scroll to anchor function.

```
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll").offset().top
      },
      'fast');
  });
```

Code is working fine on the homepage.
But on all other pages it is returning the error below

"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')"

It is driving me crazy. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: are you sure you have `#scroll` element on your pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because the element that matches the `#scroll` selector does not exist on those pages that threw the error. When that happens, `$('#scroll').offset()` returned `undefined`, and you cannot access `top` from `undefined`.

To fix this, you will probably need to ensure the element exists before attempting to invoke the logic:

```
const $scroll = $('#scroll');

if ($scroll.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $scroll.offset().top
    }, 'fast');
}
```